# Что было интегрировано в Hotspot из JRockit?

Tags: java, jvm, hotspot

Правильно ли я понял, что Oracle несколько лет назад пообещал переносить плюшки в Hotspot из JRockit, а над последним прекратить работу?
Кроме Java Mission Control, что уже было интегрировано из интересного?

Answer (score 0):

В результате объединения `JRokit` с `HotSpot` был убран `PermGen` и он был [заменен](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.ru/2013/02/java-8-from-permgen-to-metaspace.html) на `Metaspace`. Т.е. Информация о загруженных классах теперь храниться в нативной памяти. Что позволяет этой области памяти динамически расти и динамически уменьшаться, плюс флаги `PermSize` и `MaxPermSize` начиная с `java 8` недействительны.